# How would I use a Swing Timer in this case?

Tags: java, swing, timer, actionlistener

My question is how would I use a Swing timer in here so that every time a player lives, I want the code to pause for a few seconds and set the ImageIcon of label2 to an image that the user can see. This code is for a Russian roulette game btw. I've spent about a day trying random methods that I could find, but I either didn't do them properly (thread.sleep) or they caused some sort of error.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    PanelCasino panel = (PanelCasino) component;
    frame = new JFrame();

    for(int x = 1; x < 2; x++)
    {
        int num = (int)(Math.random() * 6+1) ;     
        int num1 = (int)(Math.random() * 6+1);

        if( num == num1) //first cycle
        {
            label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("gun3.jpg")); 
            label1.setText("The other player got sprayed up!");
            panel.total += panel.bet;
            break;
        }

        if(num!= num1)
        {
            label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("gun1.jpg"));
            label1.setText("The other player lives..."); 
            //this is an example of a player living 
            //and here I want "gun1.jpg" to be visible 
            //for a few seconds before the code moves on.
        }

        int num2 = (int)(Math.random() * 5+1);   //second cycle   

        if( num == num2) 
        {
            label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("gun4.jpg"));
            label1.setText("You got sprayed up! Rip!");
            panel.total -= panel.bet;
            break;
        }

        if(num!= num2)
        {
            label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("gun2.jpg"));
            label1.setText("You live...");
        }

        int num3 = (int)(Math.random() * 4+1); //third cycle

        if( num == num3) 
        {
            label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("gun3.jpg"));
            label1.setText("The other player got sprayed up!");
            panel.total += panel.bet;
            break;
        }

        if(num!= num3)
        {
            label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("gun1.jpg"));
            label1.setText("The other player lives...");
        }

        int num4 = (int)(Math.random() * 3+1);  //Fourth cycle

        if( num == num4) 
        {
            label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("gun4.jpg"));
            label1.setText("You got sprayed up! Rip!");
            panel.total -= panel.bet;
            break;
        }

        if(num!= num4)
        {
            label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("gun2.jpg"));
            label1.setText("You live...");
        }


        int num5 = (int)(Math.random() * 2+1); //Fifth cycle

        if( num == num5) 
        {
            label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("gun3.jpg"));
            label1.setText("The other player got sprayed up!");
            panel.total += panel.bet;
            break;
        }

        if(num!= num5)
        {
            label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("gun1.jpg"));
            label1.setText("The other player lives...");
        }

        //Last(6) cycle
        label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("gun4.jpg"));
        label1.setText("You got sprayed up! Rip!");
        panel.total -= panel.bet;
    }

    panel.label3.setText(""+panel.total);
    panel.revalidate();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please describe the problem you have, and where in your code it happens. Please add any error message you encounter. Also provide a [MCVE], not just a single method taken out of context. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The following code demonstrates using a `Timer` for removing an icon from a `JLabel` after `DURATION`. 
This can also be used as a demonstration of [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you were expected to post:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimerTest extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    private static final int DURATION = 4000;
    private JLabel label;
    private ImageIcon icon;
    private String imagePath = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Crystal_Project_bug.png";
    private Timer timer;

    public TimerTest() throws IOException {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout(5,5));

        JButton btn = new JButton("Fire");
        btn.addActionListener(this);
        add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        URL url = new URL(imagePath);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
        icon = new ImageIcon(image);

        label = new JLabel(); //create a blank lable
        add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //setup timer to remove label's icon
        timer = new Timer(DURATION, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                label.setIcon(null);
            }
        });

        //note you could initialize using a lambda expression
        // timer = new Timer(DURATION, (e) -> label.setIcon(null) ) ;
        timer.setRepeats(false); //timer should run once
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(new Dimension(300,350));
        window.add(new TimerTest());
        window.setVisible(true); //make it visible at the end
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        timer.stop(); //in case it is running
        label.setIcon(icon); // add icon
        timer.start();  //fire to remove icon
    }
}
```

Don't hesitate to ask for clarifications as needed.